# place search icon to the front of an input without altering existing styles

Tags: html, css

Have the attached markup and css.

I want to place the search icon to the front of the input without altering the 100% width of the input.

I would like to use absolute positioning but then when the user places the focus on the input the cursor will be over the image.

Is there a way round this?

```css
form-control__input {
  margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.form-control__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.input__default {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-control__input">
  <div class="form-control__wrapper"><svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="ng-element" data-id="d1ec30cc21c0cdbdc697b4afd1ce6469" overflow="visible" filter="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal; width: 16px; height: 16px;"><path d="M15.566 13.68l-3.467-3.466c-.018-.019-.04-.032-.059-.049a6.56 6.56 0 1 0-1.875 1.875c.017.02.03.04.048.06l3.467 3.466a1.334 1.334 0 0 0 1.886-1.886zM6.56 10.846a4.286 4.286 0 1 1 0-8.572 4.286 4.286 0 0 1 0 8.572z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#AEAEAE" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" id="ctrl1" aria-describedby="ctrl1-error" type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `label` to be able to have the focus when clicking the icon and add more padding left to the input to cover the space of the icon. Don't forget `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid having overflow when setting `width:100%`.

```css
form-control__input {
  margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.form-control__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}

.input__default {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-control__input">
  <div class="form-control__wrapper">
  <label><svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="ng-element" data-id="d1ec30cc21c0cdbdc697b4afd1ce6469" overflow="visible" filter="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal; width: 16px; height: 16px;"><path d="M15.566 13.68l-3.467-3.466c-.018-.019-.04-.032-.059-.049a6.56 6.56 0 1 0-1.875 1.875c.017.02.03.04.048.06l3.467 3.466a1.334 1.334 0 0 0 1.886-1.886zM6.56 10.846a4.286 4.286 0 1 1 0-8.572 4.286 4.286 0 0 1 0 8.572z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#AEAEAE" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" id="ctrl1" aria-describedby="ctrl1-error" type="text">
    </label></div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to consider the SVG as a background of the input:

```css
form-control__input {
  margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.form-control__wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}

.input__default {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" style="mix-blend-mode: normal; width: 16px; height: 16px;"><path d="M15.566 13.68l-3.467-3.466c-.018-.019-.04-.032-.059-.049a6.56 6.56 0 1 0-1.875 1.875c.017.02.03.04.048.06l3.467 3.466a1.334 1.334 0 0 0 1.886-1.886zM6.56 10.846a4.286 4.286 0 1 1 0-8.572 4.286 4.286 0 0 1 0 8.572z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" fill="#AEAEAE" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>') 5px center/16px 16px no-repeat
  #fff;
}


body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-control__input">
  <div class="form-control__wrapper">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="input__default form-control" id="ctrl1" aria-describedby="ctrl1-error" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```